# Actor Model is it ideal for Controlling Concurrency

Tags: concurrency, actor-model

so I am thinking of using the actor model to solve a problem I currently have. For brevity, I have made up a scenario so we don't get too technical.

Lets say I have 3 benches but each bench supports a different amount of people:

- Park Bench 1 supports 3 people simultaneously
- Park Bench 2 supports 5 people simultaneously
- Park Bench 3 supports 2 people simultaneously

Upfront I know which bench to route too however, what I don't have context of is how many people are sitting on the bench. What I want to do is block any further people from sitting on a bench if its full but when a seat becomes available allow them to sit on it.

For some reason, the Actor model popped into my head but I am not sure whether this is the correct approach and perhaps there is alternative approach to solving my problem in which case I am keen to hear.

I envision creating 3 actors `ParkBench1Actor` `ParkBench2Actor` `ParkBench3Actor` and somehow control the number of live actors. I believe concepts such as pooling can help in these scenarios http://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#pools-vs-groups.

Would appreciate peoples thoughts on this and tell me whether I have lost the plot a little :)

Comment: As best I can see, Actor is not the correct approach. I would use a counting semaphore on each bench. I implemented one using a mutex and condition variable. These two primitives are available in all environments. A bit hard to grok, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

The actor model is distinguished from other techniques by virtue of its ability to *run processes on any arbitrary machine within your computing domain.*  So if this capability fits your use case, then yes, it is ideal for your purposes.

However, a *process* is a relatively coarse-grained computational unit, and because of that, it's not appropriate for all scenarios.  You wouldn't, for example, try to distribute the sorting of an ordinary array to actors unless the array was enormous.  Instead, you would employ a finer-grained mechanism like threads and futures.

Map/Reduce engines like Hadoop/Hive (which take a big-data problem, break it into smaller pieces, fan it out to multiple machines and then perform an aggregation on the individual results) do justify a process-based, Actor-like model due to the huge amount of data involved.

Comment: My minimal knowledge of Actor is that it supports concurrency because each process has its own data and there is no interaction among processes, correct? I don't know how in this scenario the interaction of contending for limited resources would fit the Actor model. It seems to me that each 'bench' would need a counting semaphore (something I have implemented and used in the past).

Comment: Well, each actor could be talking to a centralized database.  The database has its own concurrency mechanisms.

Comment: That is illuminating. About 20 years ago I created a multi-threaded database transaction server shell, and it had a limited number of "thread slots" to handle requests coming in via HTTP. The only shared state I had to manage was the counting semaphore, and each thread talked to the database as though it was the only thread. If that is Actor, wow, I deserved a raise back then. I guess it is Actor. Hmm.

Comment: There is a slight detail which is missing, in hindsight I should of added. The person on the bench will be making an external call to a third party (http) hence the need for blocking and controlling the number of actors in play.

Comment: I have to disagree with the first sentence.  As Hewitt et al described it, there's no requirement that any of it be distributable across processes or systems.  What differentiates the actor model is its notion that actors's behaviors are limited to spawning new actors, exchanging messages with other actors and modifying their own internal state.

Comment: @blrfl: All of which you can do with ordinary classes if you don't cross process or system boundaries.  The characteristics you describe are what make the actor suitable for crossing such boundaries.